# How to fix nextjs flash on redirect to another page?

Tags: reactjs, redirect, next.js

How to fix nextjs flash on redirect to another page??
I am using router.push('/') when users login, but the page flashes for a second then the user is redirected to another page.

**here is the code:**

```
const { user } = useAuthContext();
const router = useRouter();

useEffect(() => {
  if(!user){
    router.push('/user/login')
  }
}, [user])
```

How can I redirect the user with Flash?

Comment: You can't really prevent the page from rendering if you're doing the redirect on the client-side. You could add a loader/placeholder until the `user` check is done to avoid rendering the actual page's content.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what the flash mean.
But Try this:

```
const router = useRouter()

useEffect(() => {
    if(!router.isReady) return

    if(!user){ 
        router.push('/user/login') 
    }
}, [router.isReady])
```

Comment: Hi Khashaa thanks for your answer, But it didn't work for me,

This blog post (https://theodorusclarence.com/blog/nextjs-redirect-no-flashing) explains well Next.js redirects without flashing content,

But I didn't understand the code